# Wxpython GUI is not same on python2

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.4

I'm trying to change the code written in python3 to python2.4. Python3 version code run on window well but in python2.4 and Centos5.11, GUI is not same even it run same code.

[image]

in window, python3

[image]

in centos, python2.4

The gui code is below:

```
class Panel(wx.Panel):
global WTIME
def __init__(self, parent, site):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent,wx.ID_ANY, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.Size(600,100), style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
    self.site = site
    bSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.canvas = PlotCanvas(self, 0)
    self.canvas.SetYSpec("none")
    self.canvas.Draw(drawBarGraph(self.site), xAxis=(0,12), yAxis=(0,1))
    bSizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(bSizer)
    self.canvas.SetEnableGrid(False)
    self.Layout()

def updateGraph(self, site_log):
    self.canvas.Draw(drawBarGraph(self.site, site_log), xAxis=(0,WTIME), yAxis=(0,1))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="NoName", size=(1250,500))
    self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1, size=(1250,500))
    self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1,1,1400,1600)

    topSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    panelSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    panelSizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    panelSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    panelSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.p1 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE1")
    self.p2 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE2")
    self.p3 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE3")
    self.p4 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE4")
    self.p5 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE5")
    self.p6 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE6")
    self.p7 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE7")
    self.p8 = Panel(self.scroll, "SITE8")
    self.panels = [self.p1, self.p2, self.p3, self.p4, self.p5, self.p6, self.p7, self.p8]

    panelSizer1.Add(self.p1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer1.Add(self.p2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer2.Add(self.p3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer2.Add(self.p4, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer3.Add(self.p5, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer3.Add(self.p6, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer4.Add(self.p7, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)
    panelSizer4.Add(self.p8, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND,5)

    topSizer.Add(panelSizer1, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    topSizer.Add(panelSizer2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    topSizer.Add(panelSizer3, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    topSizer.Add(panelSizer4, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    self.scroll.SetSizer(topSizer)
    topSizer.Fit(self.scroll)



    menu = wx.Menu()
    windowtimemenu = menu.Append(101, "Set Window Time", "Minute")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSetWtime, windowtimemenu)
    menu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About", "About")
    exitmenu = menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "EXIT", "Close")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exitmenu)
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    menubar.Append(menu, "Menu")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
    self.e = threading.Event()
    self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

    self.Show()
```

My questions...

1. Does wxpython run differently on py2, py3?
2. How can I show the same GUI on centos like windows.

Comment: wxPython uses "native elements" when they are available ... that means centos uses centos versions of any element it can ... and windows will use any native control it can...  some sizer stuff tends to work a little different in py2 vs py3 but basically they look the same ... afaik QT uses its own controls so you have an app that looks the same across platforms ... but it might look funny to centos users... another option that looks the same across platforms would be kivy

Comment: ok... it seems I chose a bad option. Thanks for your comment, I'll try with kivy.

Comment: Also note that wxPython 4 isn't compatible with Python 2.4. Kivy only support 2.7 and up as well.